Конфиг Nginx для клиента и сервера на одном VPS
На одном VPS c Ubuntu развернут и запущен клиент на http://localhost:3100 и сервер на http://localhost:4200. Привязан домен test.com, получен SSL сертификат Letsn crypt через Certbot. Как настроить конфиг Nginx чтобы при переходе по https://test.com открывался клиент запущенный на VPS http://localhost:3100 и взаимодействовал с сервером запущенным на этом же VPS на http://localhost:4200 ?
В данный момент конфиг выглядит так:
server {
  server_name test.com;

  location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

location /{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3100;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = test.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  server_name test.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}


С этим конфигом что-то не так?

в консоле браузера все запросы к localhost:4200 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Если в вашем браузере откуда-то берутся запросы к localhost:4200, значит вы накосячили в html/css/js коде и nginx тут вообще ни при чём

У меня на клиенте в html/css/js коде все запросы делаются на http://localhost:4200

Ну вот значит исправляйте код клиента и nginx тут вообще ни при чём

Они должны идти на https://test.com или (https://ip_server) или нет разницы ?

Они должны идти туда, куда они могут и должны идти, а куда они могут и должны идти — вы как админ сервера сами решаете. А если клиент и сервер находятся на одном домене, то указывать домен вообще нет необходимости — достаточно слать запросы на /api без всяких там http и доменов, браузер сам подставит домен из текущего адреса

Спасибо. Я предполагал что это работает так: я перехожу на сайт test.com, далее идет переадресация  на клиент localhost:3100 который запущен на vps, а далее клиент обращается к серверу запущенному на vps по адресу localhost:4200

Вы путаете терминологию, в показанном конфиге nginx выполняет не перенаправление, а проксирование
